# Who performed the works of John Adams for the Civilization 4 soundtrack?

Tags: civilization-4

Title says it all. My google-fu is apparently insufficient to answer this question for myself.

Who performed the works of John Adams for the Civilization 4 soundtrack?

Comment: I honestly have no idea.  There's nothing in the game's credits about it, and I own the "complete edition" box set that's got extra DVDs and a book with interviews with the designers, and none of that has any additional information.  I'd speculate that perhaps they did some sort of synth version of the music arranged by the music team working on the game, but I'm not a music expert.

Comment: This is going to be hard to find online, but the company is still very much alive. I recommend sending them an e-mail :)

Comment: Good idea Oak. I opened a ticket with Firaxis support (!) since there was no other easy way to contact them. We'll see what they say.

Comment: Support tells me they have no information about this, and they don't seem interested in putting any work into finding out. I guess I'll hope someone in the know stumbles upon this question.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_in_the_Civilization_video_game_series) says the orchestral samples are from the Vienna Symphonic Library, which has scores by members of the Vienna Philharmonic.  Is this what you're asking? The source for this says its in the Civilization IV manual, page 224.

Comment: John, thanks for the help, but I don't think so. It seems unlikely that the "orchestral samples" they're referring to in that sentence are the John Adams pieces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tracks are all ripped directly from the Earbox. (I personally ripped them myself and edited them too.) Of course, we officially licensed the music, but it was just easier to take the music from my personal collection rather than get Nonesuch to send us some tracks.

Comment: I'm confused as to exactly what you are answering.  Is it from your personal collection (you presume)? Is it from Earbox?

Comment: from my personal copy of Earbox, so the performances are by the musicians from that box set.